# Disable date input - MUI MobileDatepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI MobileDatePicker and having trouble removing the pencil button which changes the view. My goal is to just enable the user to select a date and not type a date.

[image]

```
<MobileDatePicker
  label="For mobile"
  value={value}
  onChange={(newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  }}
  components={{
    ActionBar: () => <div />,
    OpenPickerIcon: () => <div />
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivedatepickers-demo-mui-x-forked-06ujov?file=/demo.tsx:703-1044)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to hide the  button.
Use this selector

```
.MuiPickersToolbar-content button {
  display: none;
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsivedatepickers-demo-mui-x-forked-owq3e4?file=/style.css)

Comment: Thanks. How do I go about adding an id and targeting only a specific datepicker? I added            DialogProps={{ id: 'date-picker-id' }} but it doesnt seem to popup on the dom.

Comment: i guess with a specific class